# Simple_form path issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form, rails-routing

Here is what I have in my view:

```
<%= simple_form_for :artist, :url => url_for(:action => 'upvote', :controller => 'artists'),
    :method => 'post' do |f| %>
  <%= f.input :choose_an_artist, :selected => "first artist", collection: [["first artist", 1], ["second artist", 2], ["third artist", 3], ["fourth artist", 4]] %>

  <%= f.submit "Vote" %>
<% end %>
```

My ArtistsController:

```
def upvote
  @artist = Artist.find(params[:choose_an_artist])
  @artist.liked_by current_user

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html {redirect_to :back }
  end
end
```

routes.rb:

```
resources :artists do
  member do
    put "like", to: "artists#upvote"
  end
end
```

I am getting the following error:

```
No route matches {:action=>"upvote", :controller=>"artists"}
```

What could be causing this? How do I get this to work so that the user can select an artist from a collection and vote for that artist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several issues in your code:

First, you defined your route as `PUT` and you are forcing
    `simple_form` to produce a `POST` form. Change `method: :post`
    to `method: :put` in your view and you should be all set.

Second, you need to define your route according to your controller and action name:

```
resources :artists do
   member do
     put :upvote
   end
 end
```

Third, you defined your route as `on: :member`. That means that it needs an `artist_id` to generate. In your setup, you need to define the route `on: :collection`. I'd also better use the route path method instead of `url_for`, it's way easier to spot this errors.

```
resources :artists do
   collection do
     put :upvote
   end
 end
```

And change the `url_for` part for `update_artists_path` (if that's the correct route from `rake routes`).

Another issue not related to your question: `:choose_an_artist` is not an attribute defined in `Artist` model. This will cause another error when rendering the form.

I'd either rename that per the actual attribute name you are selecting, `:id` and change the controller accordingly (my choice), or change the form helper from `f.input` to a non-model related [`select_tag`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper/select_tag) and keep the names as they are.

Comment: I just tried this now, and i'm getting the exact same error. Any ideas?

Comment: The errors are showing when I try to render the view that has the form in it, before I even get a chance to try to submit the form.

Comment: can you add the results of ``rake routes`` in the console? We are looking for the line that defines your upvote route.